# Visible counter for specific item in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I am working on Angular 10 project where I want to visible counter only for specific item.

Since I am using 'ngFor' counter is visible for all items in the list. Request you to please guide me through it. Below are the details

> Note : Want to make similar to E-commerce cart functionality

**Html Page**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4" *ngFor="let prod of productlist; let index = index">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{prod.product_image}}" alt="" width="350" height="350"></a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <a routerLink="product/{{prod.id}}">{{prod.pname}}</a>
        </h4>
        <h5>$ {{prod.Price}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{prod.description}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <small class="text-muted">{{prod.rating}}</small>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="isShowncartbutton" (click)=AddtoCart(prod,index)>Add to cart</button>
            <div class="input-group" *ngIf="isShown">
              <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus"  (click)="Removingone(prod)" data-field="quantity">
              <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="1" [(ngModel)]="counter" name="counter" class="quantity-field">
              <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" (click)="Addingone(prod)" data-field="quantity">
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class ViewAllProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  productlist: Product;
  constructor(private productservice: ProductsService) { }
  isShown: boolean = false;
  isShowncartbutton: boolean = true
  counter: number = 1;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productservice.getAllProducts().subscribe(data => {
      this.productlist = data;
    });
  }

  AddtoCart(prod, index) {
    console.log(prod);
    this.isShown = !this.isShown;
    this.isShowncartbutton = false;

  }

  Removingone(prod) {
    this.counter = this.counter-1;
    if(  this.counter ==0)
    {
      this.isShown = false;
      this.isShowncartbutton = true;
    }
  }

  Addingone(prod) {
    this.counter = this.counter+1;
  }

}
```

Attaching snapshots for more clarification.

> 1. After clicking on Add to cart. My counter is visible.
> 2. Unfortunately it is showing for all items where as i have clicked on 2nd item. So ideally counter should be visible for it only and not
>    for all.
> 3. Same is in case of counter, if I click on '+' value is incremented for others too

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either add a counter on the product object, or create a counter object, with an entry for each product (i'm assuming each product has a unique identifier, like and ID, if not, you can use the index number from the ngFor - though that is more error prone):

instead of counter being a number, create it as an Object:
`counter = {};`

your template can be something like:

```
<input type="number" step="1" max="" value="1" [(ngModel)]="counter[prod.id]" name="counter" class="quantity-field">
```

and when you update the product list, reset the counter object:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productservice.getAllProducts().subscribe(data => {
      this.productlist = data;
      this.counter = {};
      data.forEach((d) => { 
        this.counter[d.id] = 1
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, My each product have unique id. I have attached the screenshots for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your counter,isShowncartbutton and isShown property should be part of the Product model class, now it's a common attribute for all the products.

**Model class:**

```
    export interface Product{
     counter: number;
     isShowncartbutton: boolean;
     isShown: boolean;
     .../* rest of the class properties */
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="prod.isShowncartbutton" (click)=AddtoCart(prod,index)>Add to cart</button>
        <div class="input-group" *ngIf="prod.isShown">
          <input type="button" value="-" class="button-minus"  (click)="Removingone(prod)" data-field="quantity">
          <input type="number" step="1" max="" value="1" [(ngModel)]="prod.counter" name="counter" class="quantity-field">
          <input type="button" value="+" class="button-plus" (click)="Addingone(prod)" data-field="quantity">
        </div>   
      </div>
```

**Component.ts**

replace this. key with prod. for the above mentioned attributes. Run this code to set the property to true by default.

this.productList.map(item => item.isShowncartbutton = true);

```
export class ViewAllProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  productlist: Product;
  constructor(private productservice: ProductsService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productservice.getAllProducts().subscribe(data => {
      this.productlist = data;
      this.productList.map(item => item.isShowncartbutton = true);
    });
  }

  AddtoCart(prod, index) {
    console.log(prod);
    prod.isShown = !prod.isShown;
    prod.isShowncartbutton = false;
  }

  Removingone(prod) {
    prod.counter = prod.counter-1;
    if(  this.counter ==0)
    {
      prod.isShown = false;
      prod.isShowncartbutton = true;
    }
  }

  Addingone(prod) {
    prod.counter = this.counter+1;
  }

}
```